# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined in jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Additional Info component which uses react navigation:

```
export class AdditionalInfo extends NavigationPureComponent {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: <Button icon="close" onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />,
  })

  buildNavigator = () => {
    const { extendedDescriptions } = this.nav.params
    const tabs = {}

    extendedDescriptions.forEach(({ caption, description }, index) => {
      tabs[`Tab${index}`] = {
        screen: () => (
          <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: color('white') }}>
            <Wrapper style={{ paddingTop: spacing() }}>
              <SafeAreaView>
                <Html html={description} />
              </SafeAreaView>
            </Wrapper>
          </ScrollView>
        ),
        navigationOptions: {
          title: caption,
        },
      }
    })

    return createMaterialTopTabNavigator(tabs, {
      backBehavior: 'none',
      lazy: true,
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: color('b'),
        inactiveTintColor: color('b'),
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: color('b'),
        },
        scrollEnabled: extendedDescriptions.length > 3,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: color('white'),
        },
      },
    })
  }

  render () {
    const AdditionalInfoNavigator = this.buildNavigator()

    return <AdditionalInfoNavigator />
  }
```

My additionalInfo.test.jsx file looks like:

```
describe('Additional Info', () => {
  test('Additional info component Exists', () => {
    const length = 4
    const extendedDescriptions = Array.from({ length }).map((value, index) => ({
      caption: `Tab ${index}`,
      description: `${lorem}`,
    }))
    const obj = shallow(<AdditionalInfo navigation={{ extendedDescriptions }} />)
  })
})
```

I am trying to write a test to check existence of this AdditionalInfo component and maybe a few more however, I am getting a weird error stating

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

      15 | 
      16 |     console.debug(extendedDescriptions)
    > 17 |     const obj = shallow(<AdditionalInfo navigation={{ extendedDescriptions }} />)
```

I feel am I not providing everything the test instance of AdditionalInfo needs? Or am I not using shallow correctly?

I am using the NavigationPureComponent which is defined as:

```
export const NavigationPureComponent = navMixin(PureComponent)
```

```
const navMixin = (CurrentComponent) => {
  class Nav extends CurrentComponent {
    get nav () {
      const value = new Navigation(this)
      // reset `this.nav` to always be value, this way the this
      // get nav function only gets called the first time it's accessed
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'nav', {
        value,
        writable: false,
        configurable: false,
      })
      return value
    }
  }

  Nav.propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  }

  return Nav
}
```

Comment: what is a NavigationPureComponent?

Comment: Editing question now

Comment: How do I make it work with that? any ideas?

Comment: I guess I need mount for this as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How are you importing the Component into your test?

You haven't described it above so I imagine you don't see it as an issue.

I've seen this error before. When exporting a component as a class, you have to import the component into your test as an object.

Try this:

```
export class AdditionalInfo extends NavigationPureComponent {}
```

When you're importing into your test:

```
import { AdditionalInfo } from '../pathToYourComponent'
```

Comment: I am importing it. just that the above code does not reflect it

Answer (score 1):

answering just if someone find it as me.

```
//if exporting as 
export class AdditionalInfo extends NavigationPureComponent {}
//then import
import { AdditionalInfo } from '../pathToYourComponent'
```

```
//if exporting as 
class AdditionalInfo extends NavigationPureComponent {}
export default AdditionalInfo
//then import
import AdditionalInfo from '../pathToYourComponent'
```